# New Salesforce Layout Dreamforce 2012

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, page-layout

This year at dreamforce I noticed a slightly altered salesforce layout, especially the salesforce header section. When you look at the keynotes, you can actually see the different header in the youtube videos ([Youtube Video](http://youtu.be/VZUT9KpJvNk?t=12m14s))

What I saw in this new layout was the possbility of having notifications (which is a long awaited feature in my opinion) I was wondering when this was going to be publicly available and more importantly, if we, developers, would be able to hook into those notifications, and possibly send our own.

[image: Image Link]

Comment: Nice catch. I missed the new look during the keynotes. I know at DF11, the Touch demos they were showing also had a notifications section. I definitely think it is something they are working on.

Comment: There's not currently any publicly available info, but there are a few hints on the partner portal if you have access. It's all under the kinds of NDAs that you really, really don't want to break though.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this page [this page](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jCnkAAE&utm_source=buffer&buffer_share=ca5c1):

The new layout is advertised by Salesforce already! As far as I know the new toolbar will be available across all pages, but only contact records will be updated with the new page layouts at first. Rest will follow after.

Comment: You're not really answering any of PJC's questions in actuality. His questions were: 1) when will it be publicly available? 2) can developers hook into the notification framework? While the information you share is interesting, I'm not really sure it gets to the point of this question.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty astute observation! I didn't notice it at all, I'm assuming if it went unmentioned they were showing either *a development version of the site* or *some extension they use internally*?

More importantly: *Did you hear anyone from Salesforce mention it in a session?* Perhaps someone interal to SFDC development could give us the sneak preview?

`Safe Harbor` ...?

Comment: Definitely the Safe Harbor, but I was just curious. And I attended several developer sessions, keynotes and others, saw the header multiple times, but it didn't got mentioned in the sessions where I was.